# Is it possible to pass more than one paramter in a partial function in scala to return something?

Tags: scala

I'm interested in know if partial functions in Scala can accept more than one paramter to transform, such as

```
val test: PartialFunction[Int, Boolean, String] = { case d: Int if d > 0 => "one" }

test(0, true)
```

Here I want to pass in a int and a boolean value so it can re-evaluate it into a string, is this possible?

Comment: One option would be to use a tuple `(Int, Boolean)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alextsc mentioned in a comment, use a Tuple as the input type for the function:

```
val test: PartialFunction[(Int, Boolean), String] = {
  case (d, b) if (d > 0) && b => "one"
}

test((0, true)) // or test(0 -> true)
```

You can scale this out to (almost) any number of arguments by using a higher arity tuple type:

```
val test4: PartialFunction[(A, B, C, D), String] = {
  case (a, b, c, d) => s"$a, $b, $c, $d"
}
test4((new A, new B, new C, new D))
```

Comment: You don't need the extra parenthesis. `test(...)` works fine.

Comment: @jwvh that's true, but I'm choosing to leave the extra parenthesis in my example to emphasize the fact that we are passing a tuple, as opposed to passing 2 (or 4) individual arguments.

Comment: @jwvh auto-tupling is being deprecated and taken away in the future.

Comment: @dylan, how would I specify the types of d,b in your example like:    case (d, b): (Int,Boolean) if (d > 0) && b => "one" ?

Comment: @chonglawr In that case, the type signature of the PartialFunction guarantees that `d` will be an `Int` and `b` will be a `Boolean`, so you don't need to specify within the `case`. If you really wanted to, you could do `case (d: Int, b: Boolean)`.

Comment: @wheaties, thanks!  The IDE didn't give me any warnings but I see that the REPL does.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't make any sense if you take  a look of the purpose of the PartialFunction. Basically you implicitly use a Parital in a match-case statement. 
As @Dylan stated already you could use a Tuple type or you could use a case class which is kind-of the great thing with PartialFunctions.

```
case class Func3[A,B,C](x:A, y:B, z:C)

val p:PartialFunction[Func3[Int, Int, Int], String] = {
   case Func3(a, b, c) => (a+b+c).toString
}

p(Func3(1,2,3))
```

According to this example a Tuple would make more sense. But maybe it will profit the design of your application.